# 3D printing a part without experience in 3D design

Tags: 3d-design

I have a height-adjustable table, but the height cannot be adjusted as a gear in the motor has worn out cogs and it will not spin. The motor is functional so the only thing I need is to somehow get a that particular part. I have tried searching for the motor itself on eBay, and I found one, but it would cost more than the table did and I dont want to do that unless I know there is no other option.

I am inserting some images of the part and the engine

[image]

[image]

[image]

What I am searching/asking for, is some kind of database where I might find the 3D design or something like that. I have been trying to learn AutoCAD or a similar design tool, but for a beginner level this seems too complicated.

Comment: I seriously wonder if this part can be 3D printed as the original part, an injection molded nylon part, already failed.

Comment: I've seen this failure in a garage door opener gear set. It's wear rather than failure, but I agree that it's not well suited for 3D printing. Perhaps a 3D printed version to be cast or injection molded.

Comment: these nylon gears fail under load as a safety measure and might be purchaseable as spares.

Answer (score 2):

### The part is ill-suited for FDM plastic printing due to design

The part can certainly be printed on an FDM machine, but injection molded nylon is one of the best gear materials to begin with, and they fail in a very controlled manner that limits damage. PLA would shatter, ABS can't hold such loads, ASA is super hard to print...

### The part might be usable if SLS printed

Nylon powder printing using Solid Laser Smelting might produce an appropriate replacement part, though of a slightly lesser quality than injection molded.

### Check if you can find it in a catalog

Often, these are industry-standard parts. Some of the biggest catalogs for industry standard parts, that also offer 3D models are [McMaster-Carr](https://www.mcmaster.com/) and [RS Components](https://www.rs-online.com/). If you can dimension our the part you need, you might find that part on their catalogs. As the motor carries german text, I assume you're in Europe, so McMaster-Carr sadly doesn't deliver there, but their CAD catalogue is better.

### Look for replacement parts or refurbishing kits

Your part has a number on its label - It's an **OKIN OG 01**, with a specific design variant under its serial number. Used motors with gearboxes of this type sell for 30 €, and new motors with gearbox trade for 100-120 €... And their teeth gears are available as separate parts for about 15 €. The [spare part listing I found](https://www.dieolan.de/online-shop/riemenantriebe/og-32z-24-h-ipx4/#cc-m-product-9974214595) incidentally shows that the gear you look at is a stack of two gears, one of them splined on the other:

[image: Schneckenrad 1-gängig für Riemenmotor von OKIN, Völker]